# React input onChange only registers one keypress

Tags: reactjs

Here is the relevant code:

```
onAnswerChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const answerID = e.target.id
    const answerVal = e.target.value
    this.setState( (prevState) => {
      let allAnswers = prevState.answers
      allAnswers[answerID] = answerVal
      return {answers: allAnswers}
    })
  }
  generateAnswerInput = () => {
    const id = this.state.nAnswers
    const answerInput = (
      <div key={id}>
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder={`Answer #${id+1}`}
          id={id}
          value={this.state.answers[id]}
          onChange={this.onAnswerChange}
          disabled={this.state.disabled}
        />
        <i
          id='delete-button'
          className="fa fa-window-close-o"
          aria-hidden="true"
          onClick={this.deleteAnswer}
        ></i>
      </div>
    )
    this.setState( (prevState) => ({inputToRender: [...prevState.inputToRender, answerInput]}))
  }
```

Please excuse the spaghetti code. Right now the corresponding value in state does change (the answers array), but it only registers one character. Additionally, the input doesn't update to show the character in the input field. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way I generated the inputs and fixed the problem. For anyone else who may have a similar set up, I am fairly certain that the input did not update when typing because the input itself was stored in state.